# SQL Athena/Presto to convert time duration to DD HH MM format

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have tables with 2 columns of timestamp. My goal is to have the difference  between those 2 timestamp columns, but the format should be DD HH MM.

The table looks like below:
[image]

Using **date_diff** function, I can get the time difference in minutes, but I'm stuck at what to do next. What I would like to have is table like below:

| ID | Time 1 | Time 2 | datediff(minutes) | time difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-06-01 07:30:12 | 2023-06-12 10:31:54 | 16021 | 11d 3h 1m |
| B | 2023-06-01 09:30:45 | 2023-06-01 10:31:50 | 61 | 0d 1h 1m |

Any idea how to do it in Athena/Presto? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract two dates which will result in `interval day to second` and then format it "manually":

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (id, Time1, Time2) AS (
    values
        ('A',   timestamp '2023-06-01 07:30:12', timestamp '2023-06-12 10:31:54'),
        ('B',   timestamp '2023-06-01 09:30:45', timestamp '2023-06-01 10:31:50')
)

-- query
select *,
    date_diff('minute', time1, time2) "datediff(minutes)",
    cast(day(Time2 - Time1) as varchar) || 'd ' || cast(hour(Time2 - Time1) as varchar) || 'd ' || cast(minute(Time2 - Time1) as varchar) || 'm'
from dataset;
```

Output:

| id | Time1 | Time2 | datediff(minutes) | _col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-06-01 07:30:12 | 2023-06-12 10:31:54 | 16021 | 11d 3d 1m |
| B | 2023-06-01 09:30:45 | 2023-06-01 10:31:50 | 61 | 0d 1d 1m |